# How to combine countBy and filter in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have following data array:

```js
const data = [
  { year: 1900, title: 'test 1' },
  { year: 2000, title: 'test 2' },
  { year: 2000, title: 'test 3' },
  { year: 2000, title: 'test 4' },
];
```

My aim is to get an array of years where each given year appear more than twice:

```js
[2000]
```

the countBy is fairly easy to achieve by:

```js
_.chain(data)
.countBy('year')
.value()
```

which returns the following object:

```js
{'1900': 1, '2000': 3}
```

I'm stumbling upon the filtering part. I tried the following but it returns me an empty array:

```js
_.chain(data)
  .countBy('year')
  .filter((o) => {
    o > 2;
  })
  .value();
```

What would be the correct way?

Comment: I removed my answer. But to leave it as a comment, one problem in the current code is that the filter predicate lacks a return, so it always return "undefined", therefore the list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `_.filter()` with `_.pick()` because filter would return only the values (`[3]`), and not keys (the years). You should also return from the callback - `o => o > 2`.
Afterwards, get the an array of the keys (the years), and map them to numbers (if needed).

```js
const data = [{"year":1900,"title":"test 1"},{"year":2000,"title":"test 2"},{"year":2000,"title":"test 3"},{"year":2000,"title":"test 4"}];

const result = _(data)
  .countBy('year')
  .pickBy(o => o > 2)
  .keys()
  .map(Number) // <- if you want the years as numbers
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { year: 1900, title: 'test 1' },
  { year: 2000, title: 'test 2' },
  { year: 2000, title: 'test 3' },
  { year: 2000, title: 'test 4' },
];

const yearTitlesMap = _.groupBy(data, 'year');
const yearsAppearingMoreThanTwice = _.filter(_.keys(yearTitlesMap), year => yearTitlesMap[year].length>2);

console.log(yearsAppearingMoreThanTwice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```